# While loop for checking title and add a number if it already exists

Tags: php, while-loop

I want to get the title out of a form and write it to the database. But if the title already exists I want to add number 1 to the title. I can fix that on my own but the problem is how can I (after the 1 is added) check again and if title +1 already exists make it title +2 and so on...
Any ideas how I have to construct a while loop that does that?

```
$title = $_POST["title"]; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [my_table] WHERE title='$title'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["title"]);
  //$title + add 1 to the title

} else {
  $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["title"]); 
}
```

Comment: You could use unique key for title in database and use ON DUPLICATE query.

Comment: if title+n will be your title and n will be incremental always, fetch last record from the table with limit 1, and then update accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to get the count of how many registers with the same title you have. For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM [my_table] WHERE title='$title'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result);
$count = $row['count'];
```

Then:

```
if($count > 0) {
  $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["title"]);
  $title .= $count;

} else {
  $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["title"]); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. Only thing that you should change is in the if statement Put an '$' before count.

Comment: My bad! Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do this entirely from PHP, I would get a list of all matching titles from the DB in one go, and then keep trying new numbers until one doesn't match:

```
$title = $_POST["title"]; 

//Get everything from the database that starts with $title
$sql = "SELECT title FROM [my_table] WHERE title like '$title%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//Create a list of existing titles
$aTitles = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $aTitles = $row['title'];
}

//Now see how many numbers we have

$iNum = 0;
$sTempTitle = $title;

while (in_array($sTempTitle, $aTitles)){
    //This one exists. Try the next number
    $iNum++;
    $sTempTitle = sprintf('%s %d', $title, $iNum);
}

$title = $sTempTitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Having `title` and `number suffix` as part of the title is not a good practice.

The better way to achieve that is to have a `title` column with `count` column, where you would increase `count` `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. You would have to set the `title` column to be `UNIQUE`. Then you can just build your title on `SELECT` by concatenating `row['title'] . "-" . row['count']`.

If for any reason you want to keep the current structure, i.e. the title is either:

- `<title>`
- or `<title-count>`

you would have to read in the existing title by using `title LIKE 'some_title%`.

- if it doesn't exist add it, if it exists, just add the new row;
- if it already exists, update the row by increasing the count (note that you would have to parse the title first, i.e. split by `,` and get last element - this is your number.

NOTE: This is not thread-safe and you would have to use SQL transactions for this  to work properly.